# Why class instances still share same memory of deep copied list inside?

Tags: python

I declared these variables as class context. Just delete the declaration outside the function.

---

I have a class. In its __init__ function, I created a list like this:

```py
self.__test_list = deepcopy([])
```

Then I append about 50 objects(instances), after using this list, I create new instance of this class. Also append about 50 objects. And the two instance shared this `self.__test_list`! Then I tried `deepcopy()` this list when every append, delete instance when used and call `gc.collect()` even `deepcopy()` the whole instance. But it is not working at all.
I'm using Python 3.10 with anaconda.

Minimal example:

```py
import random
from copy import deepcopy
import gc

class A:
    __some_var = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__some_var = random.randint(0, 65535)


class Test:
    __test_list = deepcopy([])

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(50):
            self.__test_list.append(A())

        self.__test_list = deepcopy(self.__test_list)
        print(len(self.__test_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gc.enable()
    for g in range(1, 2):
        for t in range(1, 6):
            test = Test()
            del test
            gc.collect()
```

It is expected to print:

```
50
50
50
50
50
50
```

But it print out:

```
50
100
150
200
250
```

`__` prefix does not influence because after I remove this prefix it still behaves like that.
[image: Print Message]

Comment: Pleast post a [mre]. It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong from the description.

Comment: Why even use a `deepcopy` here? Why not just `self.__test_list = []`

Comment: Please update your question with more details of your class when you don't use `deepcopy()`.

Comment: You need to do the `deepcopy()` ***after*** you have added all the objects to the list.

Comment: I just add minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Solved by moving `__test_list = deepcopy([])` into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first mention this line: `self.__test_list = deepcopy([])`.

Nowhere in the subsequent code do you include that line.

You *do* have the line: `__test_list = deepcopy([])` which creates a class variable of that name.

However, I suspect that the `deepcopy([])` is not doing what you think its doing. What that is doing is to take the literal list `[]` and pass that to the deepcopy function which makes a deep copy of it and returns it. But the literal list `[]` is thrown away and you end up with another empty list.

This is what I suspect you want:

```py
import random

class A:
    __some_var = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__some_var = random.randint(0, 65535)


class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__test_list = []

        for i in range(50):
            self.__test_list.append(A())

        print(len(self.__test_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for g in range(1, 2):
        for t in range(1, 6):
            test = Test()
            del test
```

Output as requested.

What the above code does is to create an instance level list for each `Test` created. Each list is populated with a number of instances of the `A` class and it prints the length of the list.